# VB.NET How to list all Column in MYSQL into 1 Column in Excel using vb.net

Tags: mysql, excel, vb.net, basic

I'm trying to list the return value from MySQL  into excel using vb.net but my problem is only the first row is being inserted in Excel

Here is the return query from MySQL

| Types of Learners | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Grade 1 | 3 |
| Grade 2 | 4 |

here is my code in VB.NET

```
Dim Type_of_Learners As String
        Dim List_TypesOfLearners_for_Today As String = "SELECT survey_at_what_blh as 'Type of Learners', COUNT(survey_at_what_blh) as COUNT
                                                        FROM daily_report 
                                                        GROUP BY survey_at_what_blh 
                                                        ORDER BY count DESC"
        da = New MySqlDataAdapter(List_TypesOfLearners_for_Today, mycon)
        dt = New DataTable()
        da.Fill(dt)
        Type_of_Learners = dt.Rows(0)("Type of Learners")
        xlNewSheet.Cells(66, 8) = Type_of_Learners
```

Should I use data set?

Comment: this is because you just select first row  here `Type_of_Learners = dt.Rows(0)("Type of Learners") ` You have to loop with return dataset and fill each row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim Type_of_Learners As String
        Dim List_TypesOfLearners_for_Today As String = "SELECT survey_at_what_blh as 'Type of Learners', COUNT(survey_at_what_blh) as COUNT
                                                        FROM daily_report 
                                                        GROUP BY survey_at_what_blh 
                                                        ORDER BY count DESC"
        da = New MySqlDataAdapter(List_TypesOfLearners_for_Today, mycon)
        dt = New DataTable()
        da.Fill(dt)
       

dim i_rowIndex as integer = 66 

for each dr as datarow in dt.rows 
  Type_of_Learners = dr("Type of Learners").tostring.trim
  xlNewSheet.Cells(i_rowIndex , 8) = Type_of_Learners
  i_rowIndex += 1
next
```

Comment: it showing a error that 'table' is not a member of datatable

Comment: check edited answer .. I thought you were use dataset

Comment: welcome bro .. Please Accept answer if it solved your problem